# Why the correlation between two vectors returns NAN in matlab?

Tags: matlab, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between each line of a matrix with the mean of its columns, for example:

```
a=[1,2,3;
   4,5,6];

mean_column=[2.5;3.5,4.5];
```

but when I do the following it returns only NaNs.

```
corr(mean_column,a(1,:));
ans =   NaN   NaN   NaN
        NaN   NaN   NaN
        NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I need to extract statistics from the vector of correlations, but these NaNs don't allow me to do that. What is happening? is there a correct way to replace these NaNs?

Comment: I thought corr2 solved my problem, but not always, I still have NaNs in some parts. :-(

Comment: The inputs to corr are `N-by-P1` and `N-by-P2`. You need to put the number of samples on the first dimension (make the mean vector a column, and transpose `a`).

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code.

```
 % initiate 2 columns, notice the transpose.
 a=[1,2,3; 4,5,6]';

 % calculate a column based on mean of a.
 mean_a = mean(a,2);

 corr(mean_a,a)     
 ans =
     1.0000    1.0000
```